# Can't find SDK Manager.exe in Android SDK folder

Tags: android, sdk

I need to install some packages in `Android SDK Manager`, but in my `SDK` folder there isn't the **.exe** file (There is only the `AVD Manager` and the folders).

How can I find it? My `SDK` works normally with `Android Studio`, without problems, it's strange that SDK **Manager.exe** isn't there.

Comment: C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Android\sdk. Are you looking here

Comment: If its working fine from android studio then either get its path from there or carry out a search for sdk manager in file explorer.

Comment: It's in the tools folder under the sdk.  Named 'android' on OSX and I think android.bat on Windows.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42577456/5460053

Answer (score 25):

I had to install an older version 
https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe
and update it. Going from there worked

Answer (score 1):

To open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager  in the toolbar. If you're not using Android Studio, you can download tools using the sdkmanager command-line tool.

Check this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

Comment: ANDROID STUDIO 3.0 (latest) DOES NOT CONTAIN A TOOLS MENU ITEM FOR SDK MANAGER.

Answer (score 1):

I found C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools\android.bat

When I ran it, it brought up SDK Manager.

Which was nice, because I couldn't find SDK Manager in the C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\lib folder like I was told it would be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Android SDK Manager.exe file in the following folder:

C:\Users[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (sdk1 in my case)

You can tap on that and you will get the Android SDK Manager screen.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android_sdk/tools/bin/ open cmd and type sdkmanager and hit enter you can use command prompt for it

Answer (score 0):

You can find sdk manager under command-line tools, which you will have to download by clicking the configure drop-down link under the android studio start-up wizard.

C:\Users[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin

I had trouble running from here because I didn't have the right permission. I was trying to update my SDK. I got it running from another folder on my system with the command line command:

"C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/7.0/bin/sdkmanager.bat" --update --sdk_root="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/cmdline-tools"

On Visual Studio 2022 you can look under Tools/Android/Android SDK Manager