# Standalone SDK Manager option in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have recently updated Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3. Now can't see the option "Launch Standalone SDK Manager", which is useful to check for updates, google play services, etc.

Comment: In menu Tools->Android->SDK Manager is there?

Comment: If you have an Android Project, open the project using Android Studio. Let it load completely. Go to Tools --> Android --> SDK Manager. If you don't have a project, in the landing screen for Android Studio, click the Configure arrow. It has the link for SDK Manager

Comment: In my case AVD Manager.exe and SDK Manager.exe are also not working

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is a deprecated feature: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235625 There is an option in Android Studio to "Show Package Details".

> For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
>   For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/5x6adh/android_studio_23_is_now_available_in_the_stable/deg48lj/

Comment: So now how I can see the updates for build tool version, google play services, support repository etc.... ??

Comment: Configure > SDK Manager > Show Package Details. You should also get notifications for updates.

Comment: @mFeinstein Ah, okay. Make sure the Android SDK Location is correct. I don't have that problem. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: It was working just fine with the last version, I only updated it, also, I can trigger an SDK update using the update messages from the IDE, I just cant use the settings options, but I already opened a bug report for them to take a look at it and I saw other people with the same issue, so this should be fixed soon

Answer (score 15):

Even I had this issue when I updated to Android Studio 2.3

Click on Configure on the bottom left side

[image: Then select SDK Manager]

Select the Check Box to Show Package Details on the bottom left side

[image: Select the Check Box to Show Package Details on the bottom left side]

Move between the different tabs as per your requirements.

Comment: I also think it's very hidden. Launched Android studio and found it in the menu on Mac here: `Android Studio->Preferences...->Appearance and Behaviour->System Settings->Android SDK` or search for `sdk` in the search functionality there. Hard to find "Show Package Details" on the bottom right too. But once you know it's easy.

Answer (score 12):

Can't working on Android Studio 2.3.3

On Mac :

> /Users/YourAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools

click **`android`**, you'll see standalone SDK manager

On Windows :

> C:\Productivity\android-sdks\tools

double click on **`android.bat`**, standalone SDK Manger will be launched (see image below).

[image: SDK location]

Comment: **************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

Comment: yes, the methods doesn't work any more

<br/>
**********************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
**********************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

Answer (score 7):

As the standalone sdk manager has been deprecated in favor of studio builtin sdk manager, there's a workaround to get back the standalone sdk manager.

**Step1.**
Download command line sdk tools for your platform:
http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24-windows.exe
http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24-windows.zip

the links refer to an old distribution intentionally (see note below).

**Step2.**
Copy the SDK Manager.exe, tools/android.bat and tools/lib/archquery.jar into your existing sdk to which android studio is currently being pointed.

**Step3.**
Run SDK Manager or tools/android.bat and you will get back your beloved standalone sdk manager while having latest android studio > 2.3

**Note**
if you download latest command line tools for sdk, you wont be able to find the archquery.jar which is required to run the standalone sdk utility.

Answer (score 5):

In this latest version (2.3.1 and 2.3.1+), after some digging, I found a faster way to open AVD and SDK: In the welcome interface of Android Studio, after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, a search box will jump out, then you can input "AVD", the AVD manager will come out. To open SDK is the same way.

[image]
However, AVD does not work in the welcome interface but SDK works. If you want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to quickly open AVD you must create a new project and open AVD in the project interface.

Comment: I hate that they're forcing us to use Android Studio for this stuff.  I don't want to create a project in Studio in order to access the AVD.  I'm using NativeScript, this is not acceptable.

Comment: In the latest version of Android Studio (`2.3.3`) `AVD manager` doesn't pop up anywhere in the `SDK Management` (even though the official documentation says so). Very frustrating indeed

Comment: thanks a lot...was struggling to open SDK Manager for last 2 hours

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Xamarin user, you can install the [Xamarin Android SDK Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/using-the-sdk-manager/), available on the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager) which will give you an interface like this:

[image]

> NOTE: The Xamarin SDK manager has to be accessed from visual studio, but it will (should) work on both windows and mac

Comment: This is great. I was having problems with the default Android SDK Manager. This one works.

Answer (score -1):

You can open it from your SDK path which in my case is

> C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

[image]

Double click on `SDK Manager.exe` and it will open standalone SDK manager, refer attached Screenshot.