# Launch Standalone SDK Manager Option is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

Suddenly my Android Studio option to open Standalone SDK Manager is missing.
Actually a strange bug is in Android Studio, where if i am importing project and some build tools are missing, it shows an error. I install it , gradle sync it then still the problem persists.

Screenshot :-
[image]

Comment: look at the sdk tool, check if you have android sdk build tools

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577166/standalone-sdk-manager-option-in-android-studio-2-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standalone SDK Manager option in Android Studio 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577166/standalone-sdk-manager-option-in-android-studio-2-3)

Comment: Everyone on stackoverflow is hellbent of proving that this question is a duplicate. I have googled it before posting. Can i open the Standalone SDK Manager some how through command line or something ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature gone deprecated.

Comment: Everyone on stackoverflow is hellbent of proving that this question is a duplicate. I have googled it before posting. Can i open the Standalone SDK Manager some how through command line or something ?

Comment: I think it's not possible.

Comment: You can't open the standalone GUI, but you can use the command line version: `sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat`