# Android Studio 2.3 sdk manager not open

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I had update android studio 2.2.3 to 2.3. After updating Standalone SDK manager not showing. So, I am trying to launch **SDK Manager.exe**  from path(C:\Android\SDk\SDK Manager.exe) but not opening SDK manager.

How can i solved this problem?

Comment: are you able to open it directly from studio?

Comment: No. directly not open,

Comment: It is a deprecated feature from Android Studio 2.3. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42577456/6482350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standalone SDK manager has been deprecated, the new one can be accessed from the bin directory of the SDK:

```
android_sdk/tools/bin/
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Comment: But this is just command line. I think the standalone graphical sdk manager has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file--->setting---->Android SDK

Check your SDK path and then lauch your SDK manager again otherwise try to update your sdk along with android studio sdk inaterface.

Comment: I had already try this but standalone sdk manager not launch.