# Failed to resolve appcompat-v7:v27.+

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

When creating the first project.

Tell me please. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Connect to the internet and click on install reprosetory

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764397/how-to-install-repository-com-android-supportappcompat-v7

Comment: Please do not use `+` in your dependency versions

Answer (score 0):

open SDK manager and install repository of version 27 then it will work either you can check which API level install properly you can change into the gradle like this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
}
```

to this if you have API level 26 :=

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
}
```

you can change like this then your problem will solved.

Comment: By the way - `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'` is compiling much more than just maps

Answer (score 0):

Just click on "install repository and sync project" in your error. It will install the required repository and solve your problem.

Comment: Button "Install repository and synchronize project" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all my colleagues. Button "Install repository and synchronize project" does not work. 
27 version is already installed.

[image]

I changed the 27 version to 25 and the error disappeared.

[image]