# Setting up SDL2 on Windows Android

Tags: java, android, ant, sdl-2

I was following [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/android_windows/index.php) tutorial to setup SDL2 on Windows Android and I am facing some issues:

1. No SDK tools package includes **SDK Manager.exe** anymore. And **SDK Manager.exe** is mentioned everywhere on the tutorial (Steps 5, 7, 8 and 12).

   - Regarding step 8 I downloaded the whole android studio just to use the SDK Manager from its interface and download Android 4.0.3 (API 15).
   - Regarding step 12, as SDK Manager.exe does not exist anymore I tried to set the folder for the ANDROID_HOME to C:\androiddevdir\android-sdk\tools as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702790/cant-find-sdk-manager-exe-in-android-sdk-folder).
2. At step 19, when I try to run **ant debug** the build does not succeed as expected and I got the following error

   > Cannot find C:\androiddevdir\android-sdk\tools\tools\ant\build.xml imported from C:\androiddevdir\SDL2-2.0.5\SDL2-2.0.5\android-project\build.xml

   And no, there is no C:\androiddevdir\android-sdk\tools\tools\ant\build.xml file, neither at C:\androiddevdir\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml without the extra tools subfolder. Actually there is just one build.xml at the C:\androiddevdir... the one that tries to import another.

Any help?

Comment: About (1): It seems now we have `tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat` instead, which is basically the same thing, but without GUI.

Comment: I finally managed to download an older  version of SDK tools and make it work with that.

Comment: Sadly, we'll have to figure a way to work with the new SDK anyway.